# Ubuntu updates to be moved to different partion

Tags: partitioning

I have partions in my HDD. it has been divded into 100 GB, 200GB and 200GB.
Whenever I am installing updates, they go to the main partion which is only 100GB.
is there a way to move it to other partions?

Comment: 100GB should be *more than enough* for a large amount of packages and the updates. You really want to move other files using the rest of the 100GB to another partition.

Comment: What? I never had more than 40GBs on root partition (if that's you meant with “main partition”) and never had any problem. 100GBs are way more than usual.

Comment: There *are* ways to move these data to other partitions: you could change mount points or use symlinks to make some of the important directories (e.g., `/usr`) point to the other partitions. You can also resize partitions, or put other data on other partitions to free up space (for example, if `/home` is in the 100 GB partition, you could put it on one of the others). We can explain any of these methods (or others) in greater detail, but to give you good advice we should know more about why 100 GB is not enough. If a 100 GB system partition is filling up fast, you may have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, filesystem partitions are used to hold specific parts of an OS or user data, such as system files, temporary files, files used by servers, or users' home directories. Each partition is mounted at a particular point in the unified directory tree -- for instance, at `/home`, `/var`, or `/usr`. Because the `/home` directory holds users' home directories, putting it on a separate partition isolates user data from system data. Other directories can be isolated in a similar manner. This can be useful in performing backups, for security reasons, to help simplify system upgrades, and so on.

This is different from Windows, which is much more haphazard in the way files are managed -- in Windows, you might create a partition and populate it with both program files and user data files. In some sense this is more flexible, but it also encourages a type of unstructured and inconsistent setup that would make a professional Linux/Unix administrator cringe.

In any event, for most desktop systems, if you split `/home` off from `/`, the latter need be no larger than 5-30GiB, depending on how much software you install. Installing software updates won't greatly increase the space demands, since the new software *replaces* existing software, so the space required won't go up much. There are exceptions to this rule, of course; for instance, most servers store data in `/var`, so if you run a Web server with gobs of Web pages, you may need lots of space in `/var` (and might therefore consider splitting it off into its own partition).

It's unclear from the original question just how those three partitions are being used. Those sizes might be reasonable for some purposes, but I suspect they were chosen based on previous experience with Windows. If one partition is actually filling up, it might be better to resize the partitions and use them in a more Unix/Linux-like way than to try to move data between the partitions. More details about where the partitions are mounted, how full they are, and what's being stored on them would be helpful in providing more specific advice.

For more general information on this topic, see [this introductory article I wrote on the subject](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unixfilesys/index.html) or read the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS).](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)